# How to increase disk size of kubernetes nodes programmatically

Tags: kubernetes

We are running out of disk space for containers running on our nodes.  We are running k8s 1.0.1 in aws.  We are also trying to do all our configuration in software instead of manually configuring things.
How do we increase the disk size of the nodes?  Right now they have 8gb each as created by https://get.k8s.io | bash.  It's fine if we have to create a new cluster and move our services/pods to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do so setting the `MINION_ROOT_DISK_SIZE` environment variable before creating the cluster. However this option was [just merged yesterday](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/11459), so it may not be available yet unless you use the cluster/kube-up.sh script from HEAD of the repository.